# Using fetch() to get data from API

Tags: javascript, json, fetch-api, uncaught-reference-error

I'm using `fetch()` for the first time to get some data from the API: 'https://www.codewars.com/api/v1/users/thenarfer'.

My goal is to `console.log` the data. I believe the data to be in JSON format.

The error I get with the following code is:

> **Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined**

Is POST or GET the correct approach? How do I continue from here?

```js
fetch('https://www.codewars.com/api/v1/users/thenarfer', {
    method: 'GET',
    mode: 'no-cors',
    credentials: 'include',
    body: JSON.stringify(data),
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
  }).then((res) => res.json())
  .then((data) => {
    console.log(data)
  })
  .catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

Comment: can this be because of data you are passing in body?

Comment: Pretty sure `data` in stringify is not defined.

Comment: It seems to work fine without all the options `fetch('https://www.codewars.com/api/v1/users/thenarfer').then(...`

Comment: The duplicate isn't actually a duplicate of _this_ problem. As OddDev points out, you haven't defined `data`. (The use of multiple variables named `data` was confusing). The duplicate does cover the next problem you'll have though.

Comment: Thanks a lot! As you pointed out there are at least two problems. 'data' and 'no-cors'. I will try to resolve both of them and post a new question with the progress. @Quentin

Comment: @Reyno You solved it all for me! Thank you! You should have heard the "Wow" that came out of me when I tried this!